# Is there a non-trivial solution for the Dirichlet problem $- \Delta u = u$ in $\Omega$ a bounded domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to know if the following problem

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u &= u \ \text{in} \ \Omega,\\
u &= 0 \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary, has a non-trivial weak solution.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Observe that if there is a non-trivial weak solution $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, then $1$ is an eigenvalue of $-\Delta$.

Consider two cases.

Case $1$) $\lambda_1 < 1$:

From the weak formulation of the eigenvalue problem of $-\Delta$,

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v dx - \int_{\Omega} u v dx = 0, \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega).$$

If $v = \varphi_1$, then

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla \varphi_1 dx - \int_{\Omega} u \varphi_1 dx = 0. (1)$$

From the weak formulation of the eigenvalue problem of $-\Delta$,

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla \varphi_1 \nabla v dx - \lambda_1 \int_{\Omega} \varphi_1 v dx = 0, \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega).$$

If $v = u$, then

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla \varphi_1 \nabla u dx - \lambda_1 \int_{\Omega} \varphi_1 u dx = 0. (2)$$

From $(1)$, $(2)$ and the hypothesis that $\lambda_1 < 1$, follows that

$$0 = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \varphi_1 \nabla u dx - \lambda_1 \int_{\Omega} \varphi_1 u dx > \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla \varphi_1 dx - \int_{\Omega} u \varphi_1 dx = 0,$$

which is an absurd.

Case $2$) $\lambda_1 = 1$:

From the weak formulation of the eigenvalue problem of $-\Delta$,

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v dx - \int_{\Omega} u v dx = 0, \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega).$$

I'm stuck here and I don't know how to proceed. I would like to know what I can conclude in the case $2$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proof in case 1 is incorrect - you are assuming $u$ is non-negative which is not necessarily the case. In fact, the statement you are trying to show in case 1 is wrong since you could have $\lambda_1(\Omega)<\lambda_k(\Omega)=1$ with $k\geqslant 2$.